# JavaScript, get the value of input field on entry

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page with an input field that the user enters a value into. The HTML code looks like this:

```html
<div class="d-flex mg-b-0 mb-3" id="cbWrapper2">
    <input type="number" name="message_average" class="form-control" id="id_message_average">
</div>
```

I'm trying to use JavaScript to get the value entered by the user so that I can then compare it against another value and write out the result, but I'm not sure how I collect the initial value being entered. What I have so far:

```js
<script>
  var value = document.getElementById("id_message_average").value;
  console.log(value);
</script>
```

I'm just trying to write the value out for now so that I can tell it's working. Do I need to put it into some kind of event listener maybe when the user clicks onto another input field, or is there a way to have the script fire when a character is added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed events to use to listen to changes in the input. One of them is called `input`, and you can use it like below.

> The input event fires when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element has been changed. More on MDN's [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).

```js
var input = document.getElementById("id_message_average");
input.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
  console.log(input.value)
});
```

```html
<div class="d-flex mg-b-0 mb-3" id="cbWrapper2">
    <input type="number" name="message_average" class="form-control" id="id_message_average">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you have add event listener.

```
let userInput = document.getElementById("id_message_average");
userInput.addEventListener("input", (e)=> {
console.log(e.target.value)
})'
```

Comment: I like this approach of using the event to access the value, but I believe it should be `e.target.value`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Didn't notice actually I missed that. Thank you again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onClick** function. If you choose onClick then you must need a **button**. Here is the example,

```
<form>
  <div class="d-flex mg-b-0 mb-3" id="cbWrapper2">
    <input type="number" name="message_average" class="form-control" id="id_message_average">
  </div>
  <button type='button' onclick="getInputValue()">Click me</button>
</form>

<script>
function getInputValue() {
  var value = document.getElementById("id_message_average").value;
  console.log(value);
}
</script>
```